# How to create anchor href using Html.Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, anchor, html-helper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render plain HTML links in Asp.Net MVC loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624697/how-to-render-plain-html-links-in-asp-net-mvc-loop)

I want to create something like this

```
<A href="#section2">Section Two</A>
```

using ASP.Net MVC's Html.Helper. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add your own helper for that:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string SectionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string URL, string display)
    {
        return String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", URL, display);
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
@Html.SectionLink(section.Anchor, section.Name)
```