# Extension method call not working in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

I've created an extension method to render a plain HTML link via MVC as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474535/how-to-create-anchor-href-using-html-helper?lq=1):

```
namespace MyProj
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string SectionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string URL, string display)
        {
            return String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", URL, display);
        }
    }
}
```

I've added references in the `web.config` and the `views/web.config` can reference it in the page and it Visual Studio doesn't give any errors:

```
<h1 class="site-title">@HtmlHelpers.SectionLink("https://stackoverflow.com/", "Home")</h1>
```

Once I run the project I get an error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'SectionLink' takes 2 arguments
```

I'm stuck on this bit. Visual Studio is happy with the reference but doesn't seem to recognise it's an extension method judging by the error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would need to be `@Html.SectionLink(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the method as an extension method:

```
@Html.SectionLink("abc", "xyz")
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple but couldn't see the wood for the trees.